# Convolution Neural Network for regression using pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to do create CNN for regression purpose. Input is image data. 
For learning purpose , i have 10 image of shape `(10,3,448,448)`, where 10 are images, 3 are channel and 448 are hieght and width.
Output lables are `(10,245)`.
Here is my architecture

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32,64, kernel_size=5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3*3*64, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 245)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        #x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2(x), 2))
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv3(x),2))
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        x = x.view(-1,3*3*64 )
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

cnn = CNN()
print(cnn)

it = iter(train_loader)
X_batch, y_batch = next(it)
print(cnn.forward(X_batch).shape)
```

Using batch size 2 i am expecting data shape produced by model is `(2,245)`. But it is producing data of shape `(2592, 245)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after self.conv3 you have tensors of shape [2, 64, 108, 108] which produces [2592, 576] after reshape. So this is where 2592 comes from.
Change the lines:
"self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3*3*64, 256)"
and
"x = x.view(-1,3*3*64)"
so that they use proper image size after the layers.

below is the fixed code:

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32,64, kernel_size=5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(108*108*64, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 245)

    def forward(self, x):
        print (x.shape)
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        print (x.shape)
        #x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2(x), 2))
        print (x.shape)
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        print (x.shape)
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv3(x),2))
        print (x.shape)
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        print (x.shape)
        x = x.view(-1,108*108*64 )
        print (x.shape)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

cnn = CNN()
print(cnn)

# X_batch, y_batch = next(it)
print(cnn.forward(X_batch).shape)
```